# Is there a way to create a table with nodes as cells in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

While it is pretty easy to create a table of *labels* in Graphviz, I have not come across a method that teaches a way to create a table of *nodes*. All the nodes are standalone and clickable svg elements. This can, of course, be done with HTML and div etc. But can we do the same without leaving the Graphviz world?

See figure
[image: table of nodes]

Comment: this is usual by archived by adding extra invisible edges and nodes

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz does not support nodes within "html".
Nor, (to my knowledge) does Graphviz support any SVG "onclick" events (for any nodes).
You might consider postprocessing the SVG output to add the "onclick" code.